# “Error loading documents” in Firebase Firestore

Tags: linux, firebase, ubuntu, google-cloud-firestore

My recently launched app has 385 users and suddenly I'm seeing this error in the Firebase console (note that refreshing the Firebase Database should display a list of all user documents). It seems to be something different from what other SO developers have posted. I haven't had any problem displaying user records in the Firebase console until today. I tried refreshing the page; didn't help.

Comment: Is this happening only in a specific machine or it’s also happening from other devices such as your mobile or personal computer? Also, did you tried to open an incognito window, disable all browser extensions and load the console? Can you see any further error in the developer’s console of your browser that you can share with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that my daily document read quota (50K reads) was reached due to the way I designed the app. I redesigned it to minimize reads and that solved the problem.